# Arnold's ODE computation of phase velocity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

In *Arnold's ODE* he defines "phase velocity vector of the flow" as

$v(x) = \dfrac{d}{dt}g^t(x)\lvert_{t=0}$

As an example, he asked the readers to find the flows on the lines for $g^t(x) = x+t$, the answer provided is $1$.

Question, why can't we differentiate the $x$ term as well?

So in the above example we would have:

$\dfrac{dg^t(x)}{dt} = \dfrac{dx+t}{dt} = \dot x + 1$

Doesn't $x$ depend on t? That's the definition of the solution isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the flow $g^t(x)$, $x$ denotes the initial value which is constant along the trajectory. The derivative of a constant is, of course, zero.

Comment: I thought initial value of a differential equation $\dot x = f(x,t)$ was $x_o$ not $x$

Comment: @TheSilenceoftheCows: That's the situation described in the Theorem just after the Problem you're asking about; there Arnold does write it as $g^t x_0$.

Comment: @TheSilenceoftheCows: This notation only works for autonomous ODE $\dot x=f(x)$. For general $\dot x=f(t,x)$ the flow needs 3 arguments, for instance as $g^t(t_0,x_0)$ to signify the dependence on the full initial point, not only the value $x_0$.